# Why can't I import in Javascript service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, javascript-import

So I have a service worker in order to implement FCM to my web app, and I can't fix the following issue.

This is my code:

```js
importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.9/firebase-app-compat.min.js", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.9/firebase-messaging-sw.min.js")

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  ...
});

getMessaging(firebaseApp);

console.log('Firebase messaging service worker is set up');
```

And these are the issues I get in the console

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.9/firebase-app-compat.min.js' failed to load.`

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.9/firebase-messaging-sw.min.js' failed to load.`

Any solutions?

Comment: Did both scripts fail to load? or just the second one?

Comment: @scunliffe Both of them. I said at the bottom that the other import failed too. But I'll edit the post so it is as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file that contain this script in **public** directory and try next script.

```
self.importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.9/firebase-app-compat.min.js", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/9.6.9/firebase-messaging-sw.min.js")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the console shows the same error